# Is this problem about local,and global variable? I don't know what this doesn't work.(basic python)

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

This code doesn't work.

error says:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'on' referenced before assignment

```
arr = []
for i in range(4):
    arr.append([0 for t in range(4)])

on=1

num_r = 0
def go_r(d):
    for i in range(d):
        arr[num_r][i+num_r] = on
        on +=1
    return arr

print(go_r(4))
```

but this code(↓) works.

```
arr = []
for i in range(4):
    arr.append([0 for t in range(4)])

on=1

num_r = 0
def go_r(d):
    for i in range(d):
        arr[num_r][i+num_r] = on
    return arr

print(go_r(4))
```

Difference between two codes is the upper code includes "on +=1"

I want my code to print [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]].

So I insert "on +=1" in upper code.

What should I do?
I don't know what's the problem on the upper code.

Comment: In your first code fragment you are modifying *on* but in the second you're just reading it. In your first fragment add *global on* inside the *go_r()* function

Comment: [This](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#more-about-scope-crossing-boundaries) should explain it, with examples that are almost identical to your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
def go_r(d):
    for i in range(d):
        arr[num_r][i+num_r] = on
        on +=1
    return arr
```

In the above case, `on` variable is a local variable in `go_r` function.

Add `global on` in the function to use global variable `on`.

```
def go_r(d):
    global on
    for i in range(d):
        arr[num_r][i+num_r] = on
        on +=1
    return arr
```